# Install "info" in Debian

Tags: bash, debian, command-line, package-management, info

When I run the `info` command I get

> bash: info: command not found

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should install the [`info`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/info) package:

```
sudo apt install info
```